# How to make elements first in a list that match a given condition?

Tags: list, kotlin, sorting

Given a list and a condition, how do I make all elements that match that condition be the first elements in a list?

For example,

List:

(10, 100, 12, 12, 14, 12, 1002)

Given the condition that the element is 12, the list should now be

(12, 12, 12, 10, 100, 14, 1002)

Is this an expensive function to be done?

I've tried using Kotlins built in sorting function, but it does not sort given a specific value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list can be split into a Pair of two lists by a given condition:

```
val list = listOf(10, 100, 12, 12, 14, 12, 1002)

val result = list.partition { it == 12 }.toList().flatten()

println(result)   // Output: [12, 12, 12, 10, 100, 14, 1002]
```

See [Filtering collections: Partition](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html#partition)

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do it is to sort the entire list based on whether each item equals 12:

```
val list = listOf(10, 100, 12, 12, 14, 12, 1002)

val result = list.sortedBy { it != 12 }

println(result)   // Output: [12, 12, 12, 10, 100, 14, 1002]
```

Since Kotlin uses a stable sorting algorithm, the items that are not 12 are guaranteed to be kept in the same order.

However, lukas.j's answer might be more efficient. You'll have to test and compare the performance of each way.

Comment: Would have never thought of sorting by a boolean value. I like this. And { it == 12 } would move all items equaling 12 to the end of the result list.

Comment: Ingenious! Though I think it's sufficiently non-obvious as to need a clarifying comment, while the `partition()` answer would be clearer to the reader.